# Hide checkbox and disable select all option in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am working slickgrid js. I need to hide the checkbox in the header in slickgrid and also I need to disable select all option in the grid. Can anyone help me how could I do this in slickgrid.

Comment: Were you able to remove the select all checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

assign
show checkboxes:false,

in the options

Comment: I tried adding that to my options as such. var options = {
    editable: false,
   showcheckboxes: false
}; It did not work. Any Suggestions?